# Tableau - Fixed count of datapoints per pane

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to build a [shewhart-style control chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart) in Tableau and having trouble with setting a fixed sample size for the data points plotted on the chart. Consistent sample sizes are critical for setting accurate control limits so I'm dead in the water until I can specify that tableau only use 10-30 random rows to calculate each point on the chart.

I thought I could accomplish this by returning a random number in my query and filtering on the top N results for each pane but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to actually execute that.

Comment: can you explain more on fixed sample size for data points?

Comment: Let's say I have a process that creates a variable number of data points (30-50) per day. In order to make a statistically robust control chart I need to keep the number of data points used to compute the chart constant each day, meaning I need to take a random sample of 10 data points to construct the chart.